# Overlay the second image z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, intersection-observer

I'm having an issue with two `images`. I have 1 image (we are rucab) and a guy as second image. I'm using `intersection observer` to show first the we are rucab image and next the guy image. The problem is when the guy appear, we are rucab keeping in the front, I want the we are rucab image goes back, and the guy appears in the front, keeping the responsive, sizes and all in the same position. I tried playing with `z-index absolute positioning` but didn't work well. You can see an example [here](https://lagaleramagazine.es/rucab/index.html).

```
<div class="img-container col-lg-7">
        <div class="jumping">
      <img class="top superman active" alt="" src="img/Ilustracion%20Hombre-05.png" data-src="img/Ilustracion%20Hombre-05.png" width="100%">
        </div>
            <img class="we-are-rucab-img show-bottom" style="z-index: -1000 !important;" src="img/Letras%20We%20are%20Rucab-06.png" data-src="img/Letras%20We%20are%20Rucab-06.png" width="100%" title="We are RUCAB" alt="We are RUCAB">

          </div>
```

CSS

Img container:

```
.img-container {
    padding-top: 35px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: -2px !important;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 42%, #fbc00c 42%);
}
```

First image (we are rucab):

```
   .we-are-rucab-img {outline: 1px solid transparent;opacity: 0; transition: 1s opacity;}
.we-are-rucab-img.show-bottom {opacity: 1;  
  animation: movefromtop 1s alternate infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-fill-mode:  forwards;}
@keyframes movefromtop {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-5em);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0em);
  }
}
```

Second image (guy):

```
      .superman {opacity: 0; transition: 1s opacity;}
.superman.active {opacity: 1;  
  animation: movefrombottom 1s infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  }

@keyframes movefrombottom {
  from {
    transform: translateY(5em);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0em);
  }
}
```

JS Intersection observer:

```
// Instantiate a new Intersection Observer

let observer10 = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry10);

let element10 = document.querySelector(".home-button");
observer10.observe(element10);

let superman = document.querySelector('.superman');

function onEntry10(entry10) {
  if (entry10[0].isIntersecting) {
      setTimeout(function() {
    superman.classList.add("active");
    }, 300);
  }
}

// Instantiate a new Intersection Observer

let observer9 = new IntersectionObserver(onEntry9);

let element9 = document.querySelector(".home-button");
observer9.observe(element9);

let werucab = document.querySelector('.we-are-rucab-img');

function onEntry9(entry9) {
  if (entry9[0].isIntersecting) {
    werucab.classList.add("show-bottom");
  }
}
```